# Stackoverflow at predeployment of PersistenceUnit Jakarta EE10

Tags: persistence, eclipselink, payara, persistence.xml

The migration of a Webapplication from Java EE8 to Jakarta EE10 based on Payara Fish 6.2023.6 failed during deployment.

```
WARNUNG:   Unsupported deployment descriptors element schemalocation value https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd.
SCHWERWIEGEND:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
SCHWERWIEGEND:   Exception while preparing the app
SCHWERWIEGEND:   Exception during lifecycle processing
jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 4.0.1.payara-p1.v202304041433): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [com.eisenbahntechnik.tosPU] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2150)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2126)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:313)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:207)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:571)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:183)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1197)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepare(ApplicationLifecycle.java:511)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:613)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:552)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:376)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:582)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:574)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:376)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:573)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1879)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1755)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:604)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:150)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 4.0.1.payara-p1.v202304041433): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [com.eisenbahntechnik.tosPU] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:233)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.persistence.asm.internal.platform.eclipselink.MethodVisitorImpl$ELMethodVisitor.visitAttribute(MethodVisitorImpl.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.asm.internal.platform.eclipselink.MethodVisitorImpl.visitAttribute(MethodVisitorImpl.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.asm.EclipseLinkMethodVisitor.visitAttribute(EclipseLinkMethodVisitor.java:216)

... last 3 exception some 100 times more
org.eclipse.persistence.asm.internal.platform.eclipselink.MethodVisitorImpl$ELMethodVisitor.visitAttribute(MethodVisitorImpl.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.asm.internal.platform.eclipselink.MethodVisitorImpl.visitAttribute(MethodVisitorImpl.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.asm.EclipseLinkMethodVisitor.visitAttribute(EclipseLinkMethodVisitor.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.asm.internal.platform.eclipselink.MethodVisitorImpl$ELMethodVisitor.visitAttribute(MethodVisitorImpl.java:275)
```

The 3 exception lines above arise more than 100 times.

The persistence.xml file looks like this:

```
<persistence version="3.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemalocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="com.eisenbahntechnik.tosPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/tos</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I changed only the namespace of the ressources to jakarta.*, nothing else.

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Does logging not show more details about the internal StackOverflowError exception being caught during the deploy operation? That would be the starting point to figuring out what is going wrong.

Comment: I added the complete logging. At the end it is always 3 same exceptions 100 times.

Comment: See https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/issues/1832 which seems fixed in v4.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downgrading from Payara 6.2023.6 to 6.2023.3 it works. EclipseLink  v4.0.1 was upgraded in 6.2023.4. Waiting for new Payara release with fixed error in v4.0.2 like proposal from Chris.